# Soft Body Object deforming too much

Tags: soft-body

Basically, I was trying to apply physics to a tail so it would behave and collide with objects by itself without me having to do too much input. And I thought softbody would be perfect for this, but for some reason, my tail keeps "folding up" and breaking in strange ways. I've tried all the settings but I can't seem to find the cause.

This is how it looks:

[image]

Anyone knows why it's doing that?

Comment: To prevent it from cutting through the edge of the box, enable ‘Edge’ collision in the Soft Body Edges properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using "Soft body self collision" in the physics tab of your tail object?

I tried to emulate your work. Here is an example of how the simulation looks with and withouth self collision:

[Without self collision](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_0exCMjDeXVFXO4aVwg2VWm-3KFseyD1)

[With self collision](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FwkTuAsBlV5LMaxIxbZjaive0PTJCqMc)

To simply explain this, self collision adds balls to every vertex of your object. This allows the vertexes to not collide with themselves and keep a structure.

Here is the [old documentation](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc%3A2.6/Manual/Physics/Soft_Body/Collisions), [here the new one](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/soft_body/settings.html#physics-softbody-settings-self-collision).

Also, a really important option is stiffness. A high stiffness will make your vertexes more resistant to deformation, while a low stiffness will make your object deform more.

Here is the [file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1E20S6BwJg1Z3F4QFPcTEQVyMtkv2fyBH) with self collisions **ON**. Remember to change the settings of the balls on your file, as I did it in some seconds, and the balls would not be accurate with your setup. Just try and try again to change the size of the balls, until you get the result you want.

Comment: Huh. I always figured that self collision was for when the object gets squeezed to retain it's shape and not as a mandatory checkbox for when you want to do something like this. Well, thanks for the help man!

Comment: Well surely there are better ways which I don't know to solve this problem, but if this works why bothering ;)

Comment: All self collision does with my mesh is make parts disappear!

Comment: I would suggest opening a new question @BeeAPotato , it will make it easier to solve your problem.